# doctrine 2.2 double type to a power

Tags: mysql, doctrine-orm

Within Entity Repository:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
//....
$qb->addSelect('POWER('.$qb->expr()->abs(
                $qb->expr()->diff('c.latitude', $filter['latitude'])
            ).',2) AS ddst';
//....
return $qb->getQuery(); //to Pagerfanta with DoctrineORMAdapter
```

Errors:

```
QueryException: [Syntax Error] line 0, col 11: Error: Expected known function, got 'POWER'

QueryException: SELECT c, (POWER(ABS(c.delivery_latitude - 47.227163),2) AS ddst 
FROM MyEntity c ORDER BY ddst ASC, c.created_at DESC (this is dql error)
```

What's not right? Dql doesn't support POWER. I didn't found it in qb-expressions.

Comment: What is your problem? You actually know why it isn't working, the `POWER` function is not a native `DQL` function. You've to write yourself and add it to Doctrine2. (http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.1/cookbook/dql-user-defined-functions.html)

Comment: ok. I will try to add POWER to DQL. Actually I thought DQL support that kind of SQL Math function in some form. 
Cuz native query is not good for me. I don't know, how to pass NQ to Pagerfanta))
But, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

And... Maybe it will be helpfull for someone. Answer:

```
//app/config/config.yml

doctrine:
    dbal:
        #.....    
    orm:
        auto_generate_proxy_classes: %kernel.debug%
        # auto_mapping: true #comment this line if isset
        entity_managers:
            default:
                auto_mapping: true #from orm to here or custom mapping
                dql:
                    numeric_functions:
                        power: Acme\MyBundle\DQL\PowerFunction #or power_num: ... it's an identifier
```

src/Acme/MyBundle/DQL/PowerFunction.php:

```
<?php
namespace Acme\MyBundle\DQL;

use Doctrine\ORM\Query\Lexer;

class PowerFunction extends \Doctrine\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\FunctionNode
{
    public $numberExpression = null;
    public $powerExpression = 1;

    public function parse(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\Parser $parser)
    {
        //Check for correct
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_IDENTIFIER);
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_OPEN_PARENTHESIS);
        $this->numberExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_COMMA);
        $this->powerExpression = $parser->ArithmeticPrimary();
        $parser->match(Lexer::T_CLOSE_PARENTHESIS);
    }

    public function getSql(\Doctrine\ORM\Query\SqlWalker $sqlWalker)
    {
        return 'POWER(' .
            $this->numberExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ', ' .
            $this->powerExpression->dispatch($sqlWalker) . ')';
    }
}
```

And using (in MyEntityRepository):

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('c');
//some code
$qb->addSelect('power('.$yourNumber.',2) AS powered_num');
//'power' must be in lowercase!!!; if idetifier in config for example, 'power_num', then write 'power_num($yournumber,2)'

//some code ...

return $qb->getQuery(); //or getResult()
```

done.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same issue thanks to this Bundle:

https://github.com/orocrm/doctrine-extensions

Here is the way to process.

1) Install the library:

```
composer require oro/doctrine-extensions
```

2) Add the DQL function to your doctrine config:

```
doctrine:
    orm:
        dql:
            numeric_functions:
                pow: Oro\ORM\Query\AST\Functions\Numeric\Pow
```

That's all.

Now Doctrine know how to handle the SQL POW function.

Answer (score 0):

DQL is not SQL. It does not support a lot of the more obscure SQL functions like POWER.

If you want, you can create a native SQL query. See this doc for more info:

http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html